# Does all web hosting providers support ASP.NET websites?

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I'm totally new to deploying websites and I read some articles and facebook posts that some hosting providers does not support ASP.NET, our website was built using ASP.NET webforms, any input is appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run your windows software on a Mac computer? and a Mac computer can't run its software on windows?

A web server is a computer. In fact, say you using LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP). That's called a developer stack. If you decide to say use some other web development language? Well, you can't then just expect your software to work on that computer.

So, if you say write your software to work on IBM's WebSphere computer, then if that web hosting computer does not have those languages, coding systems and support? Then you can't run your software on that computer.

If you write your software to work with Apache web server? Then the web hosting computer will have to be setup and support running Apache.

When you develop a asp.net site? Then the web server used is IIS (internet information services). So how this works is really not different then a desktop computer.

You can even find asp.net hosting (and yes, it is in fact a windows hosting system), but some support MySQL as the database server, and don't offer say SQL server services.

So, yes you not only have to find a web hosting company that supports .net, but ALSO one that supports the systems and the tools and the software you created. You can not more just toss Mac software on your windows computer, then you can say toss some asp.net software on some computer that not even windows based.

A computer is a computer is a computer. And a web hosting computer is NOT any different in this regards.

So, you have two choices:

you can look at what your current web hosting provider supports, and then go download or whatever the developer tools for that particular web hosting plan. In other words, you look at your current web hosting, and choose the programming lanauges, database system and tools they support. If you don't use those tools then your software will not work on that web site.

Or, you can adopt a set of tools, build that software and then go find a web hosting plan that supports your particular development tools.

Keep in mind that a LOT of lower cost asp.net hosting plans do NOT support asp.net web applications. They support asp.net web sites, but not asp.net web applications. But in general, most hosting plans outline what tools and systems they support.

So when you go to a hosting provider? They have Linux plans, and then they also will have aps.net (windows) hosting plans. They are often $2-$3 more per month - but in general the cost difference is not much different at all.

So, web servers no more run software then what you have running on your desktop computer.